# Hide all popovers on document click - except the one clicked (getting wrong order of events)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue.js and I have a Calendar component with days. When you click on a day, it shows it's popover. I am trying to make it so that if you click anywhere in the document it hides all popovers. But it should not hide the one that I just opened.

I added an event listener for document click but it fires **after** the Day component's *@click* event. Which means it shows the current day's popover and then immediately hides **all** popovers. But it should first hide all popovers and only then show the Day's popover.

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
    <calendar-month-view>
        <day></day>
        <day></day>
        <day></day>
    </calendar-month-view>
</div>
```

**My Day component**

```
export default {

    template: `
        <div @click="isVisiblePopover = !isVisiblePopover">
            <popover v-show="isVisiblePopover" />
        </div>
    `,

    components: {
        Popover
    },

    data() {
        return {
            isVisiblePopover: false
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        $(document).click(event => {
            EventBus.$emit('popover-opened')
        });

        EventBus.$on('popover-opened', () => {
            this.isVisiblePopover = false
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: A couple issues:

 (1) `Day` attaches a `click`-event handler on the document on mount, so every instance of `Day` adds its own handler. If there are multiple `Day`s, clicking in the document would cause multiple `popover-opened` events.

 (2) If you only want one `Popover` to show at once, the better parent component would probably be `CalendarMonthView`, not `Day`. The calendar could then manage the popover contents based on the `Day` clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve that is to implement a kind of layout to put behind the popover, as part of the `Popover` component, taking the 100% of the screen  (invisible, or maybe with some kind of opacity). Then, you should handle that the popover will also close when the back layout is clicked, and the dialog itself wasn't clicked. It's more simplier than handling clicks in the whole document (that also handles the popover clicks!).

Here you have an example of how the popup component should be like:

```js
Vue.component('popover', {
  template: `
    <div id="popover-layout" @click="layoutClicked($event)">
      <div id="popover-dialog" ref="popoverDialog">
        Popover dialog
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    layoutClicked(event) {
      if(event.target !== this.$refs.popoverDialog) {
        console.log('Close popover!')
      }
    }
  }
});


var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```css
#popover-layout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background: silver;
}

#popover-dialog {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -75px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <popover></popover>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I click anywhere in the document outside the layout that is behind the popover?

Comment: Remmember that the layout sould take the 100% of the screen (for example, with: `position: absolute; top:0; letf: 0; right:0; bottom: 0`), so the user couldn't click anywhere else than there of the popup.

Comment: I've make a jsfiddle to ilustrate how the popover component should be like. Sorry about the delay but I had other things to do before :P. I hope it's useful for you!