# Can't get the $ref of a child inside a component. Getting undefined error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js and I am trying to get the width of both ref=“mybtn” and ref=“confirmpopover” but I can’t get the width of ref=“confirmpopover”. I can’t understand why, it is saying undefined.

> Trying to get getBoundingClientRect of undefined.

```
export default {
    template: `
    <div @click="openPopover" ref="mybtn">
        <ml-confirm-popover ref="confirmpopover" />
    </div>
`,

methods: {
    openPopover() {
        // result: 200
        console.log( this.$refs.mybtn.getBoundingClientRect().width )

        // result Trying to get getBoundingClientRect of undefined.
        console.log( this.$refs.confirmpopover.getBoundingClientRect().width )
    }
}
```

Comment: Where/when do you call this method?

Comment: on mybtn click there is a @click="openPopover" event attached

Comment: What is `ml-confirm-popover`?

Comment: Try troubleshooting this by logging `this.$refs` entirely, see what shows

Comment: Have a look to my answer to YOUR other question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54841663/2940802), that also have an example of using this.$refs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`ref` docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref):

> If used on a plain DOM element, the reference will be that element; **if
> used on a child component, the reference will be component instance**

So if you want the actual DOM element, you have to access the `$el` inside of the ref:

```
console.log( this.$refs.confirmpopover.$el.getBoundingClientRect().width )
```